# Elastic Search: Sort Numeric which is defined as String

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have scenario where I need to Sort by the specific field, which is number but is defined as String.
Is there any option where we can sort the string field as a numeric without using the **script tag** and **without performing reindex**

Comment: You mean "is number but is **NOT** defined as Number", right? or, "is number but is defined as String"

Comment: Yes,
and is defined as string instead of Number

Comment: And [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#script-based-sorting) cannot be used?

Comment: Yes...
We are avoiding to use the script tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reindex, you can update-by-query the index by modifying slightly the mapping.

Given your field is defined like this:

```
"sort-field": {
    "type": "text"
}
```

You can modify it to add a numeric sub-field as follows:

```
PUT your-index/_mapping
{
   "properties": {
       "sort-field": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {               <---- add a numeric sub-field
             "numeric": {
                "type": "integer"
             }
          }
       }
   }
}
```

And then simply update the index (add `?wait_for_completion=false` if the index is big and the update would take a substantial amount of time):

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query
```

When the update is done, you can sort by `sort-field.numeric`